# How to determine the base image of a Docker image?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-image

I am curious about what base image my image is based upon. There seems no easy and straightforward way to do that. So for example I want to know the base image of `openjdk:11-jdk`.

First of all, I am fetching the relevant image id from my local repository by doing
`docker images | grep openjdk`, which gives me below output.

```
↳ docker images | grep openjdk
openjdk 11-jdk              612d4d483eee        8 days ago          606MB
openjdk <none>              3a40000f62f1        3 weeks ago         605MB
openjdk <none>              243e95d792e3        2 months ago        605MB
```

The relevant image here is `612d4d483eee`, so I want to see the history of that image by doing `docker history 612d4d483eee` which gives me below output (I left out the `--no-trunc` option because it messes up the formatting).

```
↳ docker history 612d4d483eee
IMAGE               CREATED             CREATED BY                                      SIZE                COMMENT
612d4d483eee        8 days ago          /bin/sh -c #(nop)  CMD ["jshell"]               0B                  
<missing>           8 days ago          /bin/sh -c set -eux;   dpkgArch="$(dpkg --pr…   322MB               
<missing>           8 days ago          /bin/sh -c #(nop)  ENV JAVA_URL_VERSION=11.0…   0B                  
<missing>           8 days ago          /bin/sh -c #(nop)  ENV JAVA_BASE_URL=https:/…   0B                  
<missing>           8 days ago          /bin/sh -c #(nop)  ENV JAVA_VERSION=11.0.6      0B                  
<missing>           3 weeks ago         /bin/sh -c { echo '#/bin/sh'; echo 'echo "$J…   27B                 
<missing>           3 weeks ago         /bin/sh -c #(nop)  ENV PATH=/usr/local/openj…   0B                  
<missing>           3 weeks ago         /bin/sh -c #(nop)  ENV JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/…   0B                  
<missing>           3 weeks ago         /bin/sh -c #(nop)  ENV LANG=C.UTF-8             0B                  
<missing>           3 weeks ago         /bin/sh -c set -eux;  apt-get update;  apt-g…   9.68MB              
<missing>           3 weeks ago         /bin/sh -c apt-get update && apt-get install…   142MB               
<missing>           3 weeks ago         /bin/sh -c set -ex;  if ! command -v gpg > /…   7.81MB              
<missing>           3 weeks ago         /bin/sh -c apt-get update && apt-get install…   23.3MB              
<missing>           3 weeks ago         /bin/sh -c #(nop)  CMD ["bash"]                 0B                  
<missing>           3 weeks ago         /bin/sh -c #(nop) ADD file:8f7dc710e276f54a3…   101MB
```

I can see the layers of the image, but I see no base image.

What I usually do is going to the Docker hub page entry (https://hub.docker.com/_/openjdk) and see if there is a repository mentioned anywhere.

Luckily in this case there is a Github repository which is https://github.com/docker-library/openjdk. So I go to that repository and navigate to the Dockerfile of my specific image (https://github.com/docker-library/openjdk/blob/master/11/jdk/Dockerfile). On top of that file, I see the following line:

```
FROM buildpack-deps:stretch-scm
```

So the question is why is `buildpack-deps:stretch-scm` not visible anywhere in my command outputs? On top of that I want to know if there is an easier way of finding out the base image.

Comment: Perhaps adding the ```--no-trunc``` option to the ```docker history <image>``` command will help?

Comment: That does not help. All it does is showing the full command and no `buildpack-deps:stretch-scm` to be found anywhere. I left the --no-trunc out because it would mess up the formatting of the post.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For pulled images, I don't think there is a way to find the base image without seeing the actual dockerfile because when you pull an image, image manifest is downloaded only for the leaf layer. So the image id of the non-leaf layers in marked as `<missing>` in `docker history` and you wouldn't know the repo tags of those layers.

---

If the image is built on your machine but if you don't have the dockerfile, you can find the base image as follows:

`docker history` prints the image ids of the layers. Then you can get the repo tags using `docker inspect`. The base image used will usually be the last layer in the output of `docker history`.

eg:

```
$ docker history t:1
IMAGE               CREATED             CREATED BY                                      SIZE                COMMENT
10b4cce00fb8        3 days ago          /bin/sh -c #(nop)  CMD ["flask" "run"]          0B
824987ef6cab        3 days ago          /bin/sh -c #(nop) COPY dir:1973b65388e92428e…   406B
d4b6f433a5df        3 days ago          /bin/sh -c pip install -r requirements.txt      4.98MB
8827b3f01d00        3 days ago          /bin/sh -c #(nop) COPY file:98271fcaff00c6ef…   0B
65b8c98138e6        2 weeks ago         /bin/sh -c apk add --no-cache gcc musl-dev l…   113MB
01589531f46d        2 weeks ago         /bin/sh -c #(nop)  ENV FLASK_RUN_HOST=0.0.0.0   0B
6c4640b8027a        2 weeks ago         /bin/sh -c #(nop)  ENV FLASK_APP=app.py         0B
b4c8fc7f03d6        2 weeks ago         /bin/sh -c #(nop) WORKDIR /code                 0B
16a54299f91e        2 weeks ago         /bin/sh -c #(nop)  CMD ["python3"]              0B
```

```
$ docker inspect 16a54299f91e
[
    {
        "Id": "sha256:16a54299f91ef62cf19d7329645365fff3b7a3bff4dfcd8d62f46d0c9845b9c6",
        "RepoTags": [
            "python:3.7-alpine"   ---> Base image used in FROM instruction.
```

Following the output of `docker history` in reverse order, you can approximately recreate the Dockerfile.

---

You can also use the `chenzj/dfimage` image which runs a script which does the same to reconstruct the dockerfile.

```
alias dfimage="docker run -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock --rm chenzj/dfimage"

$ dfimage 10b4cce00fb8
FROM python:3.7-alpine
WORKDIR /code
ENV FLASK_APP=app.py
ENV FLASK_RUN_HOST=0.0.0.0
RUN /bin/sh -c apk add --no-cache gcc musl-dev linux-headers
COPY file:98271fcaff00c6efb6e58bd09ca726c29947e0cfe7031a8d98878cc01561fbbf in requirements.txt
RUN /bin/sh -c pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY dir:1973b65388e92428e30f835a67ebc8c7b00ec648fbea0717af6d501af162186b in .
CMD ["flask" "run"]
bash-3.2$
```

Comment: docker history t:1 didn't work when this answer was written. You just get missing for everything now

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jfrog artifactory, the repository server side info can be used to findout if you are using a certain base image or not.

i.e:

1 base image has manifest, sha__ , sha__ ,... files. File number is n.

2 if a image has the (n-2) number of same sha__ file names, then base image was used.

You can browse jfrog artifactory UI, install jfrog atifactory cli or jfrog go client, use search function to find above info.

Comment: This doesn't seem like a reliable method. I believe it's the case that if an image is re-built, even if it uses the same base image, it will get a different SHA.

Comment: This is the current way we check openjdk base image. The server side storage is different from docker host storage. This solution is based on jfrog product and not a generic solution.