# Is there a way to see a complete Docker image inheritance?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

For instance, I want to see which image a particular image was built FROM.  And then I want to see the one that one was built FROM, all the way up the inheritance hierarchy until I reach FROM scratch.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope. It is not possible unless you have the Dockerfiles or you have built the image on  your machine and you still have the build cache.

For the second case, you can use `docker history` to approximately rebuild the Dockerfile of an image. `docker history` prints the image ids of the layers. Then you can get the repo tags using `docker inspect`. The base image used will usually be the last layer in the output of `docker history`.

eg:

```
$ docker history t:1
IMAGE               CREATED             CREATED BY                                      SIZE                COMMENT
10b4cce00fb8        3 days ago          /bin/sh -c #(nop)  CMD ["flask" "run"]          0B
824987ef6cab        3 days ago          /bin/sh -c #(nop) COPY dir:1973b65388e92428e…   406B
d4b6f433a5df        3 days ago          /bin/sh -c pip install -r requirements.txt      4.98MB
8827b3f01d00        3 days ago          /bin/sh -c #(nop) COPY file:98271fcaff00c6ef…   0B
65b8c98138e6        2 weeks ago         /bin/sh -c apk add --no-cache gcc musl-dev l…   113MB
01589531f46d        2 weeks ago         /bin/sh -c #(nop)  ENV FLASK_RUN_HOST=0.0.0.0   0B
6c4640b8027a        2 weeks ago         /bin/sh -c #(nop)  ENV FLASK_APP=app.py         0B
b4c8fc7f03d6        2 weeks ago         /bin/sh -c #(nop) WORKDIR /code                 0B
16a54299f91e        2 weeks ago         /bin/sh -c #(nop)  CMD ["python3"]              0B
```

```
$ docker inspect 16a54299f91e
[
    {
        "Id": "sha256:16a54299f91ef62cf19d7329645365fff3b7a3bff4dfcd8d62f46d0c9845b9c6",
        "RepoTags": [
            "python:3.7-alpine"   ---> Base image used in FROM instruction.
```

See [Is there a command to find out the base image of a Docker image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59892922/is-there-a-command-to-find-out-the-base-image-of-a-docker-image/59894125#59894125)

Comment: When I run docker history, all the IMAGE values are <missing> except for the first row for a particular docker image (confluentinc/cp-kafka).  Does that mean I'm out of luck?

Comment: Yes, you are out of luck as far as I understand. if you have pulled the image from somewhere, you can try to find the Dockerfile.