# How to find out what a Docker image layer is from its hash?

Tags: docker, docker-image

When starting a Docker image:

```
$ docker run -it ruby:2.6.1 
Unable to find image 'ruby:2.6.1' locally
2.6.1: Pulling from library/ruby
22dbe790f715: Pull complete 
0250231711a0: Pull complete 
6fba9447437b: Pull complete 
c2b4d327b352: Pull complete 
270e1baa5299: Pull complete 
  ...
```

Is it possible to tell what image `270e1baa5299` is?

Answer (score 2):

You can start with [`docker history`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/history/):

```
docker history  ruby:2.6.1
```

See "[Digging into Docker layers](https://medium.com/@jessgreb01/digging-into-docker-layers-c22f948ed612)" from Jessica G.

That will give you an idea of the content of those layers:

[image: https://miro.medium.com/max/900/1*kTDjPNUqGX8ZdLidbukheA.png]

For more: [**`wagoodman/dive`**](https://github.com/wagoodman/dive)

> A tool for exploring a docker image, layer contents, and discovering ways to shrink the size of your Docker/OCI image.

Comment: For some reason, the `docker history` command gave both on my Ubuntu and macOS `IMAGE               CREATED             CREATED BY                                      SIZE                COMMENT
99ef552a6db8        14 months ago       /bin/sh -c #(nop)  CMD ["irb"]                  0B                  
<missing>           14 months ago       /bin/sh -c mkdir -p "$GEM_HOME" && chmod 777…   0B  `. Except the first one, it is all `<missing>`

Comment: @nonopolarity See https://stackoverflow.com/a/35312577/6309, and try with a more recent ruby image: `docker history ruby:2.6.6`

Comment: @nonopolarity What is your version of Docker used here?

Comment: the latest (or almost), on the Mac `Docker version 19.03.8, build afacb8b`, Ubuntu `Docker version 19.03.8, build afacb8b7f0`

Comment: @nonopolarity As in https://stackoverflow.com/a/59894125/6309, what does a `docker inspect` return for one of the missing layers?

Comment: is it true that there was a bug and some numbers are missing, but moving forward, supposedly all the newly built images and layers should have a name from its hash?

Comment: @nonopolarity no name for new intermediate layers.