# How to get base docker image tag version?

Tags: docker

I have a docker (with dockerfile) which was built from base docker with not tag (meaning it's the latest tag).

The docker was built a year ago, and I want to know which tag (version) we used.

(`FROM baseDocker`, what is the version/tag of `baseDocker`)

Is there a way I can get the tag of the base docker, the dockerfile used ?

I have tried to view the information from `docker image inspect` but I'm not sure what and where to search there

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Locate Dockerfile given image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61390606/locate-dockerfile-given-image)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a command to find out the base image of a Docker image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59892922/is-there-a-command-to-find-out-the-base-image-of-a-docker-image)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use docker history.
Check the documentation here: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/history/

Answer (score 0):

run command

```
docker images
```

it will give you following information about your docker image

```
REPOSITORY    TAG IMAGE ID       CREATED        SIZE
```